# Ajax Dynamic Menu Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm implementing a category and subcategory. However, it is using only 1 model with the gem 'awesome_nested_set', so when I click my first collection_Select, it will process my Ajax and return an instant variable for my controller and get the category for the second collection select. I'm almost done, but I still have a little problem.

1. When I load the page, it gives me an error: "might expect an instance of array". I know why this happens, it's because when I load the page, it actually loads the js, but initially, I haven't clicked the first collection_select. I can't get the value from the select and my controller cannot get the params from there too.
2. I did try to not run the partial, but my Firebug console shows me red color, but I see it can get the params from the first collection_select.

Here is my [gist.gihub](https://gist.github.com/2995276)

The full code is provided, please guide me, I need some modifications...